# PHP - OOP return objects or array?

Tags: php, arrays, oop, object

I'm just starting to learn OOP as my usual procedural approach is beginning to become messy when dealing with larger projects. I've ran into a few things i'm unsure about early on.

The idea is simply adding new members to a database, and pulling a list of existing members from the database.

I've put some comments in my code as well as the questions below.

```
class memberManager
{
    public $members;

    public function createMember($db, $array)   // Should I pass in an array or seperate items?
    {
        // Db code


    }

    public function getAllMembers($db)
    {
        // Should I return an array, then loop through in my script creating the "member" objects, or should I create and return them directly in this function?
        $dbconnection = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM members");
        $dbconnection->execute();

        $x = 0;
        while ($row = $dbconnection->fetch())
        {
           $members[$x]['firstname'] = $row['firstname'];
           $members[$x]['lastname'] = $row['lastname'];
           $members[$x]['dob'] = $row['dob'];
           $x++;
        }

        return $members;

    }
}


class member
{
    public $firstname, $lastname, $dob;

    function __construct($details)
    {
        $this->firstname = $details['firstname'];
        $this->lastname = $details['lastname'];
        $this->dob = $details['dob'];
    }
}
```

members-list.php

```
$memberManager = new memberManager();
$membersList = $memberManager->getAllMembers($db);

foreach ($membersList as $existingMember)
{
   $member = new member($existingMember);
}
```

1. When I create a new member, should I pass in an array, or each item individually? My reasons for doing an array is it allows me to add new parameters to it easy enough, especially if I'm storing a lot of data about a member, as opposed to *function createMember($db, $firstname, $lastname, $dob, etc, etc.)
2. In my "getAllMembers" function, as it pulls each member should I put them into an array as I've done here, then loop through that array on my members-list.php creating objects, or should I instantiate the member() class directly within "getAllMembers", and just return an array of objects?

Hopefully this makes sense, It's written in a bit of a pseudocode-ish manner just to highlight the problems.

Comment: This question may be better suited for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 0):

1. I will pass an array. As you said, it is easier to add a new property.
2. I will return an array of objects and I will have a member entity that it will make easier to work with the properties. My answer is just a personal opinion.

Note: this question can have multiple different answers, since, it will depends on the developer preferences

Comment: Thanks. If it's just developer preferences then that's fine, was just making sure I wasn't making a terrible start to OOP by picking up any bad habits early!

Answer (score 0):

I know I am not exactly answering your question, but for basic [CRUD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Create,_read,_update_and_delete) I would really recommend some [ORM](https://packagist.org/search/?q=orm) framework.

As for your question, I think using separate entity classes over arrays is way to go - you sacrifice flexibility but in return you can keep entity specific logic in one place, which goes well with [DRY principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself).

Please also note that your class naming is slightly off. While PHP does not definitive any naming conventions, for class names [PascalCase](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x2dbyw72(v=vs.71).aspx) is mostly used.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'll take a look into some ORM frameworks. Could you possibly explain what you mean about keeping entity specific logic in one place?